# Handling multiple and duplicate emails for Google MailApp

Tags: loops, email, google-sheets, duplicates

I am trying create a script for Google Sheets that does the following:

1) triggers on a certain date
2) compiles information from columns based on a date criteria
3) sends an email digest of multiple column values to each *unique* triggered email row

I've looked up several alternate examples, but I cannot grasp the syntax to handle step 3.

The data is generated from Google Forms submissions.

Submissions are added continuously.  Script has a time-driven trigger.

I want it to compile all data for entries by the SAME email respondent on the triggered date AND separate out data intended for different email addresses.

I've grabbed a script and altered it to the best of my ability. (see below)

Currently, it produces the following results:

1) script triggers correctly based on date
2) compiles information from triggered columns and *reports in one email to all addresses from triggered rows.* (incorrect behavior)

Currently the script runs a 'for loop' to grab all triggered data for body of email and sends ALL data to ALL emails.  I understand why it does this but I can't wrap my head around how to execute 'step 3' above.'

I think I need to create an object for the email data and run another "for loop" to isolate the reference email.

I'm not sure where to go from here, or how to grab the column value to isolate the required email.

Spreadsheet layout:

Column A: Timestamp
Column B: Recorded Email
Column C - F: Personalized Info
Column G: Requested Followup Date
Column H: Days Remaining until Followup Date

Data set starts on Row 2

Email is triggered when Column H reports value of 0.

Thank you in advance for any and all assistance

Current Script:

```
function checkReminder() {
  // get the spreadsheet object
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set the first sheet as active
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  // fetch this sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
  // is the headers, so start with row 2
  var startRow = 2


  // grab column 8 (the 'days left' column) 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,8,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var reminder_date = range.getDisplayValues();

  //grab DOB column
  var DOB = sheet.getRange(2,4,lastRow-startRow+1,1)
  var DOBrange = DOB.getDisplayValues();

  //grab ph# column
  var phnum = sheet.getRange(2,5,lastRow-startRow+1,1)
  var phnumrange = phnum.getDisplayValues();

  //Admin Date of 1st shot
  var Admindate = sheet.getRange(2,6,lastRow-startRow+1,1)
  var Admin = Admindate.getDisplayValues();

  // Now, grab the patient name column
  range = sheet.getRange(2,3, lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var patient_info_values = range.getValues();

  //grab email
  var Emailrows = sheet.getRange(2,2,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var Emaillist = Emailrows.getValues();


  var sendit = 0;
  var msg = "";
  var greeting = "This email is to remind your team to followup with the following individuals. \n \n";


  // Loop over the days left values
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
       var days_left = reminder_date[i][0];
  if(days_left == 0) {
      // if it's equal to 0, do something with the data.
      var Adminreport = Admin[i][0];
      var patient_name = patient_info_values[i][0];
      var DOB_name = DOBrange[i][0]; 
      var phnumgrab = phnumrange[i][0];
      msg = msg + " "+patient_name+"  DOB: "+DOB_name+" Phone#: "+phnumgrab+" First dose given "+Adminreport+"  \n\n";
      sendit++;
    }

  }
    if(sendit) 
  {
    MailApp.sendEmail(Emaillist, "Followup Reminder", greeting + msg);

  }

};
```

Comment: You need to refactor, and use an associative object to map between each email and its associated data. i.e. you need an object `{}` that has a key of an email, and the value retrieved by the key is an array of strings (or a long string) that will be the body of the email for this address. e.g. `var data = {}; for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { var days_left = ...; var email = /* something */; if(!data[email]) { /* initialize new email */ data[email] = [];} data[email].push(patient_name + ...); } if(sendit) { for(var email in data) { MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, data[email].join("\n")); } }`

Comment: @tehhowch 
Thank you for clarifying this.  I read this elsewhere but was unsure if it applied to my task.  I have two followups if you don't mind.  First, do I execute this second FOR loop within the first?  Second, in your example you define var I = 0 to run the loop.  If I have a previous loop with var i do I need to change the variable to something else or is that distinction handled by the synyax/brackets?
I very much appreciate your reply.

Comment: the first `for` loop is only collecting data data, yes? So, it does not make sense to call your bulk-data-consumer loop within your data-gatherer loop 2) You should change the index variable, as Apps Script has no "block scope".

Comment: @tehhowch 
Okay, excellent.  I was on the right track.  I think my syntax was incorrect.  Thanks for confirming.  I'm looking forward to working it out!  Thanks again!